# How do I chroot an SSH user to their home directory?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, chroot

I don't want to use jailkit. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I am setting up a user account on my server for a kid I tutor, so he can run a minecraft server. He will be using putty to ssh into my server, and I want to limit his filesystem access to his home directory and basically give him free reign. He will need to be able to use bash, java, and nano, but I also want to give him access to python, lynx, and emacs, and maybe curl, wget, and git.
It would be cool if I could limit the size of his home folder too.

What do I need to do to make this happen?